# Assigning Default Values To App in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, sharedpreferences

I'm implementing a generic app for different things which will retrieve data from web services, but I have to assign  a unique id to every different kind of app.

For example, if a teacher has installed this app, it should be assigned "teacher" so that it fetch only teacher's stuffed data, but if a student has installed the app, it should be assigned "student"

What I'm trying to do is every single time before app runs, It should have the information about which type of person he is either "teacher" or "student"

Kindly help me out the question mat be is not elaborated clearly but i tried.

Comment: How do you know the installation belong to a teacher? A Log-in credential? What?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @Seraphim Yes exactly you reached my point of view... Is there some tricky way if i want to assign him his type in my code when he will install app or i make different app for every different kinda person?

Comment: @Robert I'm just analysing the app before starting it

Comment: I think i should ask the user his type just for first type and the after it should not ask him and use the sharedprefernce data... thats what i guess the best way

Comment: So I I'm a student but I select "teacher" he will be able to see what he is not allowed to see...

Answer (score 2):

You can store the status of the user in a form of persistent storage. Take a look at

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

This will allow you to utilize internal/external storage.

Example with shared preferences :

To save the user use:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("User", "Teacher").commit();
```

To retrieve the user use:

```
String res = prefs.getString("User", DEFAULT_USER);
```